# Fourier transform of the Random Phase Screened Potential

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, residue-calculus

This problem is motivated from the physics side. But it does not require any background in physics.

Consider the function $g(u)$

$$\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta\left\{\frac{\sqrt{(x+u)^2-1}}{2x}\left[1-2\theta(x+u)\theta(|x+u|-1)\right]-\frac{\sqrt{(x-u)^2-1}}{2x}\left[2(\theta(x-u)-1)\theta(|x-u|-1)+1\right]\right\}}$$

where $x,\alpha,\beta$ are all positive real numbers. $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

How to compute

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{iut}g(u)\,du$$.

I tried to used the Jordan’s lemma but the problem is that the function has Heaviside step function, which may not have an analytical continuation in the upper half complex plane.

Comment: Note that the denominator of $g(u)$ is continuous in $u$ for u in $\mathbb{R}$. But it is not analytic at $|x\pm u|=1$.

Comment: Since $\theta(-x)/x$ has a Fourier transform by interpreting $\theta(-x)/x$ as a distribution. It also does not admit an analytical continuation so would jeopardise Jordan's lemma. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712012/fourier-transform-of-singular-function-fx-with-frac1x2-as-x-to0) Can we use distribution theory to solve this?